# How do I reference a cell from within a "...IF"-type function condition string?

Tags: macos, numbers

When using a `...IF` type of function (like `COUNTIF`, `AVERAGEIF`, etc.), I use condition strings:

- **e.g.** `">100"`, `"=Mr. Smith"`

Instead of using a literal from within the string, how do I (or can I) reference a different cell from within the table?

- **e.g.** `">ColA Row2"`

#### Stuff I've Tried (that doesn't work)

```
...,"=A2",...
...,=A2,...
```

Comment: Have you tried just using the cell reference directly (A2, for example)?  That works in Excel and it should be the same in Numbers.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. Please see edits to question.

Comment: That doesn't look right.  The use is `COUNTIF(Range,Criteria)`.  It should be similar to `=COUNTIF(A2:A10, "Mr. Smith")`.

Comment: @fsb - I don't know why you think it doesn't look right — that usage is correct, I have spreadsheets using it right now. This is copied directly from the documentation: **`=COUNTIF(A1:D5, “=ipsum”) returns 1, because the text string “ipsum” appears once in the collection referenced by the range.`**

Comment: It didn't look right because of how you're displaying it in your question: "...,"=A2",...
...,=A2,...".  The way it's written in the documentation is the way I use it so it does work.  Have you tried isolating the `COUNTIF` to a different cell and see if that throws an error?  Maybe it's a different part of your formula that's generating it?

Comment: Okay, I've figured out what I was doing wrong. My wrong attempts: `COUNTIF(A2:A10, "=A2")`, `COUNTIF(A2:A10, =A2)`. The correct answer: `COUNTIF(A2:A10, A2)`. I'll accept your answer if you enter one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When directly referencing a cell from within an `IF` type function, **don't** use a condition string. Also, no need to use a comparison operator.

- Condition string usage, to compare against a literal value:

  COUNTIF(A1:A20, "=Mr. Smith")
- Direct cell reference, to compare against cell `B1`:

  COUNTIF(A1:A20, B1)